# Remove all lines before specific string starts python

Tags: python, text

My output (string):

```
First Line
second something aaa
MY2 asd hello
no one nothing
```

I need to remove all linesw before `MY2`
Output should looks line :

```
MY2 asd hello
no one nothing
```

code: (not working)

```
output= '\n'.join(output.split('\n'))
for line in output:
    a=output.strip()=='MY2'
    print(a)
```

Comment: What is the output you're getting?

Comment: Only “False”  i am receiving

Comment: Hi..while we encourage you to involve in the community, please don’t thank in the question. It eventually degrades the quality of the site. See  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution, using `re` module ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/kFuq1z/1)):

```
output = '''First Line
second something aaa
MY2 asd hello
no one nothing'''

import re

print( re.findall(r'^(MY2.*)', output, flags=re.S|re.M)[0] )
```

Prints:

```
MY2 asd hello
no one nothing
```

Comment: this is best solution for me, thank you, but others could fit as well. Could you explain me what those commands do, step by step in short ?

Comment: @sygneto The regex `^(MY2.*)`: `^` - matches beginning of line. So `^MY2` will match any line that begin with `MY2`. The `.*` will match the rest of the string. Flag `re.S` means `.` character will match newline and `re.M` means that `^` will match any beginning of line.

Answer (score 1):

You can traverse through all the lines, and keep the flag if string encountered.

```
output = """First Line
second something aaa
MY2 asd hello
no one nothing """

set_print = False
for line in output.split('\n'):
    if line.startswith('MY2'):
        set_print = True
    if set_print:
        print(line)
```

Comment: from what I understood he wants to print all lines after that, so you need to keep track that if you have visited the required line or not.

Answer (score 1):

With [`itertools.dropwhile`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile) feature:

```
from itertools import dropwhile

output = '''First Line
second something aaa
MY2 asd hello
no one nothing'''

for l in dropwhile(lambda s: not s.startswith('MY2'), output.splitlines()):
    print(l)
```

The output:

```
MY2 asd hello
no one nothing
```